# sqlite database overwrites existing record than inserting new record in physical device

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am facing challenge where i am unable to insert new record into table, rather it overwrites the first record in the table.

This happens in the physical device where as it is working fine in the emulator.

Following is the code used to insert the record:

```
Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String strDate = formatter.format(date);

            //SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING);

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            /*ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            //values.put("UserId",1);
            values.put("NoQPassed", scoreValues.get("NoPassed"));
            values.put("NoQFailed", scoreValues.get("NoFailed"));
            values.put("NoQSkipped", scoreValues.get("NoSkipped"));
            values.put("SubjectName", scoreValues.get("strSubjectName"));
            values.put("CompletedDateTime", strDate);
            intRetVal= db.insert(score_Table_Name, null, values);*/

            String strQuery="insert into "+score_Table_Name+" values ('"+strDate+"','"+scoreValues.get("NoPassed")+
                    "','"+scoreValues.get("NoFailed")+"','"+scoreValues.get("NoSkipped")+"','"+scoreValues.get("strSubjectName")+"')";
            db.execSQL(strQuery);
            db.close();
```

Tried inserting using **db.insert** and **db.executeSQL**, but none help. Can someone help me where i am going wrong?

I didnt add any primary key or autoincrement key to make sure the conflict is not because of that column. Do we always need to have primary key to insert new record?

Comment: How do you know that row over writing?

Comment: I am exporting the database file from Device File Explorer and checking what is the table content in DB browser for sqlite. I find only the latest inserted values.

Comment: Make sure you are not deleting row after insert anywhere. There is no logic here that replace old data. Use to see database https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

Answer (score 0):

you can use below getCount() method to count occurrences. `if getCount(name)== 0` then do inserting. otherwise not inserting and try to log.

```
public int getCount(String name) {
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        db = Dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select count(*) from TableName where name = ?";
        c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {name});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            return c.getInt(0);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But this logic may not be valid if you say you override it. I think there is no override possibilities in that android sqlite. Please check **you might be drop your database any where before inserting new record**. It may seems like override data

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the logic behind the code you shared?